# trim ip address octet

Tags: php

I need to trim the last octet from an ip address using php. Basically I'm trying to just remove any digits after the third dot. I'm wondering if there is an out of the box solution for this? as my regex abilities are basic at best. Many thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
$trimmed = implode(".", array_slice(explode(".", $ip), 0, 3));
```

or

```
$trimmed = substr($ip, 0, strrpos($ip, "."));
```

or possibly

```
$trimmed = preg_replace("/(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3}).(\d{1,3}).(\d{1,3})/", '$1.$2.$3', $ip);
```

A more mathematical approach that doesn't remove the last digit but rather replaces it with a 0:

```
$newIp = long2ip(ip2long("192.168.0.10") & 0xFFFFFF00);
```

Comment: what more could i ask for? have a great day! :)

Comment: OMG, what a nice way to demonstrate the "there is more way to do it right" rule, respect!

Comment: If I may suggest a probably better (and faster) regex. `/^(?!0)(?!.*\.$)((1?\d?\d|25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d)(\.|$)){4}$/`

Comment: Which is the most performant one, though? Not that I need that optimisation, but given the 3 choices I feel like I should pick the fastest one while at it.

Comment: I run each of the above 4 commands on 100,000 for loop length. so the results:
#1 `$o = implode('.', array_slice(explode('.', $ip), 0, 3));`
#2 `$o = substr($ip, 0, strrpos($ip, '.'));`
#3 `$o = preg_replace("/(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3}).(\d{1,3}).(\d{1,3})/", '$1.$2.$3', $ip);`
#4 `$o = long2ip(ip2long($ip) & 0xFFFFFF00);`

results:
#1 | 0.4816ms
#2 | 0.2819ms
#3 | 0.2552ms
#4 | 0.3316ms

**preg_replace WINS!**

Comment: Thanks a lot very usefull for verifying the google ip https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27665531/how-to-find-googles-ip-address/70754702#70754702

Answer (score 2):

This will remove the last digits and the dot.

```
$trimmed = preg_replace('/\.\d{1,3}$/', '', $ip);
```

Answer (score 0):

Regexp vatiant

```
$ip = '192.168.20.10';
preg_replace_callback(
    '/^(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})$/'
    , create_function('$matches', '$matches[4] = "0"; array_shift($matches); return implode(".", $matches);')
    , $ip
);
```

You could also use ip2long and long2ip... but have no idea about "box solution" with it:

```
$ip = ip2long('192.168.20.10') - 10;
echo long2ip($ip);
```